# Insert rows in dataframe based on condition - the Tidyverse way

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a data frame

```
# 5 companies observed each day for 10 days
df <- tibble(
  company = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 10),
  value = rep(sample(100, 5), 10),
  date = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-10"), 1), each = 5)
)
df
```

Now something happens to the data and some of the company E rows are removed.

```
df_error <- df[-c(5, 10, 15, 20), ]
df_error
```

What is the simplest Tidyverse way to add back the E rows.
Value doesn't matter.
The date of the E row is the same as the D row above it.

I started with the following and wasn't sure how to proceed:

```
# Find all D occurrences
e_idx <- which(df_error$company == "D")
e_idx

# If there is not an E in the next row, get the index. These need E rows below each index value. 
rows_need_e_below <- ifelse(df_error[e_idx + 1, 1] != "E", e_idx, NA)
rows_need_e_below
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your data should have "A" to "E" companies you can use `complete` :

```
tidyr::complete(df_error, date, company = LETTERS[1:5])
```

Or more generally :

```
unique_company <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
tidyr::complete(df_error, date, company = unique_company)

# A tibble: 50 x 3
#   date       company value
#   <date>     <chr>   <int>
# 1 2020-01-01 A          87
# 2 2020-01-01 B           5
# 3 2020-01-01 C          40
# 4 2020-01-01 D          67
# 5 2020-01-01 E          NA
# 6 2020-01-02 A          87
# 7 2020-01-02 B           5
# 8 2020-01-02 C          40
# 9 2020-01-02 D          67
#10 2020-01-02 E          NA
# … with 40 more rows
```

The `value` column is by default given `NA` value. If you want to fill it with specific value you can use `fill` parameter of `complete`. For example, to fill with 0's you can do :

```
tidyr::complete(df_error, date, company = unique_company, fill = list(value = 0))
```